# Easy way to see that the Chern class is the Poincaré dual of the vanishing locus of a section?

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, vector-bundles, characteristic-classes

Let $\mathscr{L}$ be a holomorphic line bundle (perhaps smooth suffices, but I'm concerned with the holomorphic case anyway) on a smooth complex manifold $X$. We can define its Chern class via the exponential exact sequence:
$$
0 \rightarrow \mathbb Z \rightarrow \mathscr O_X \rightarrow \mathscr O_X^\times \rightarrow 0
$$
And the associated cohomology sequence which includes:
$$
H^1(X, \mathscr O_X^\times) = \text{Pic}(X) \rightarrow H^2(X, \mathbb{Z})
$$
We can use this map as a definition for the Chern class $c_1(\mathscr L)$.

It is true that if $\sigma$ is a holomorphic section of $\mathscr L$, then if we let $[\sigma]$ denote the homology class represented by the vanishing locus of $\sigma$ (the points $p$ where $\sigma(p) \in \mathscr L$ is $0$), then $c_1(\mathscr L)$ is Poincaré dual to $[\sigma]$ (at least in the case that the vanishing locus of $\sigma$ is a irreducible analytic subvariety).

Does anyone know (or know a reference for) a straightforward proof of this fact? Griffiths-Harris shows it via the curvature form definition of Chern class, but this is more hard differential geometry than I am comfortable with. I'd love a proof directly from this exact sequence, but I'd also be happy with assuming that $c_1(\mathscr L)$ as defined here agrees with the topologically-defined Chern class (i.e. defined by axioms or the Euler class or by pullback from a Grassmanian).

Comment: Classify it by a map to $\Bbb{CP}^\infty$; the zero set of the "obvious section" of this is $\Bbb{CP}^{\infty-1}$. When the domain is compact, you can tell the same story with a finite-dimensional approximation $\Bbb{CP}^N$ for $N$ large.

Comment: The subtlety here in the holomorphic setting (as opposed to the smooth setting) is that you have to pull back some power of the *dual* of the tautological bundle $\mathscr O_{\Bbb P^n}(-1)$ to talk about holomorphic sections' giving a map to $\Bbb P^n$. However, I will suggest that @Dorebell think about the meaning of Schubert cycles and look at pp. 409 ff. in Griffiths/Harris, too. By the way, the story about Schubert cycles and degeneracy loci of (smooth) sections is quite beautiful. It's not that bad to understand.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I'll try to work through the section - it seems like a nice geometric perspective.

This seems like a silly question, but how do I "pull back" the statement from the universal bundle to the specific bundle in question? Of course, if $\mathscr L$ is classified by $f: M \rightarrow \mathbb C P^\infty$, $c_1 \mathscr L = f^* c_1(\gamma)$ where $\gamma$ is the universal bundle. But the Poincaré dual of $c_1(\gamma)$ doesn't pull back - what's the relevant functorial property of Poincaré duality?